# How to selectively pass mouse events to underlying svg elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have a scatterplot with a brush layer for zooming in the data and voronois for mouse hover snapping but the problem is that the voronoi paths don't let the click event fall through to brush layer or if keeping brush on top it doesn't allow hover event to fall through to voronoi layer

Brush layer needs click event

Voronoi layer needs hover event

How should I go about the setup, css only solutions preferable

keeping brush layer on top :

[image: brush layer on top]

keeping voronoi layer on top :

[image: voronoi's tesselations over brush layer]

Comment: best case would be if both layers recieved all the events

Comment: Not possible CSS only.

Comment: I did something with js but it doesn't feel smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this on voronoi hover keeping brush on bottom, but it flickers arround the edges

```
$("#visualization-main-container > svg > g.voronoiWrapper > path.voronoi-poly").css("pointer-events", "all");

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#visualization-main-container > svg > g.voronoiWrapper > path.voronoi-poly.voronoi-movie-id-" + d.id).css("pointer-events", "none");
}, 10);
```

**EDIT :**

I finally end up using a hotkey "CTRL" to temporarily disable mouse events on voronoi layer when it is pressed down, it adds an extra step to the zoom process but it is much more smooth.

Comment: Why post this as an answer if you're dissatisfied with it? Shouldn't this be part of the question along the lines of I tried this but I'm not happy with it...

Comment: sorry am relatively new to stack overflow still learning the meta but I haven't accepted the answer its just a possible solution according to me